# MS Access/VBA type mismatch when passing arrays to function/subroutine

Tags: ms-access, vba

Can anyone explain to me why, in VBA code for a button on a form in MS-Access 2007, this gives the error "Compile error: Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected"

```
Private Sub Button_Click()
    Dim Arr() As Integer
    Foo (Arr())
End Sub

Private Sub Foo(Arr() As Integer)
    Me.Field.Value = "Foo"
End Sub
```

but this compiles fine?

```
Private Sub Button_Click()
    Dim Dummy
    Dim Arr() As Integer
    Dummy = Bar (Arr())
End Sub

Private Function Bar(Arr() As Integer)
    Me.Field.Value = "Bar"
End Function
```

The function/subroutine I'm writing doesn't return anything, but I can't get it to compile unless I assign the return value of my function call to a dummy variable, like in the Bar function above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wish to use brackets around the parameter, you must use Call, so skip the brackets:

```
Private Sub Button_Click()
    Dim Arr() As Integer
    ''No brackets
    Foo Arr()
    ''Or 
    ''Call Foo(Arr())
End Sub

Private Sub Foo(Arr() As Integer)
    Me.Field.Value = "Foo"
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems I need to read up a little more on the ways to call subroutines. Thanks.